# fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7864320 bytes) in wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I've been receiving the following error each time I attempt to update the menu in the dashboard:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 7864320 bytes) in
>   /var/sites/p/[sitename].com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php
>   on line 1369

Going off previous advice, I have deactivated all plugins one-by-one to see if one of them was causing the error, though the error remains despite deactivating all plug-ins.

Having gone into wp-db.php to line 1369, this is what it reads:

```
$error_str = sprintf( __( 'WordPress database error %1$s for query %2$s made by %3$s' ), $str, $this->last_query, $caller );
```

To expand, this is what lines 1342 to 1407 reads:

```
 * Print SQL/DB error.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @global array $EZSQL_ERROR Stores error information of query and error string
 *
 * @param string $str The error to display
 * @return false|void False if the showing of errors is disabled.
 */
public function print_error( $str = '' ) {
    global $EZSQL_ERROR;

    if ( !$str ) {
        if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
            $str = mysqli_error( $this->dbh );
        } else {
            $str = mysql_error( $this->dbh );
        }
    }
    $EZSQL_ERROR[] = array( 'query' => $this->last_query, 'error_str' => $str );

    if ( $this->suppress_errors )
        return false;

    wp_load_translations_early();

    if ( $caller = $this->get_caller() ) {
        /* translators: 1: Database error message, 2: SQL query, 3: Name of the calling function */
        $error_str = sprintf( __( 'WordPress database error %1$s for query %2$s made by %3$s' ), $str, $this->last_query, $caller );
    } else {
        /* translators: 1: Database error message, 2: SQL query */
        $error_str = sprintf( __( 'WordPress database error %1$s for query %2$s' ), $str, $this->last_query );
    }

    error_log( $error_str );

    // Are we showing errors?
    if ( ! $this->show_errors )
        return false;

    // If there is an error then take note of it
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        $msg = sprintf(
            "%s [%s]\n%s\n",
            __( 'WordPress database error:' ),
            $str,
            $this->last_query
        );

        if ( defined( 'ERRORLOGFILE' ) ) {
            error_log( $msg, 3, ERRORLOGFILE );
        }
        if ( defined( 'DIEONDBERROR' ) ) {
            wp_die( $msg );
        }
    } else {
        $str   = htmlspecialchars( $str, ENT_QUOTES );
        $query = htmlspecialchars( $this->last_query, ENT_QUOTES );

        printf(
            '<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>%s</strong> [%s]<br /><code>%s</code></p></div>',
            __( 'WordPress database error:' ),
            $str,
            $query
        );
    }
}
```

Awaiting further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Through the advice found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-92/) by user Ewout, I have gone into wp-config.php and edited

> define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );

to a much higher number. It was originally set to 256 when I tried raising it in the past. This wasn't enough, so I have chosen a number 10000 and this fixed the problem. I hope I don't run into any future issues by raising it to such a number, though it did fix the problem. I hope this helps fellow novices out a bit who are receiving the same error message.